# query not returning the latest objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm using Parse within my app. i'm trying to do a query with a limit of 10 objects ordered by descending order of the createdAt property plus I'm using the `nearGeopoint:WithinKilometers` function. When i run the query, the receive the oldest objects in the database. when i remove the limit of number of objects to be returned, the query returns the latest objects from the newest to oldest (as expected). does the limit do that? isn't it a bug? here is the code, please let me know if there is anything wrong:

```
PFQuery *postsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"user_p"];
if (city) 
{
   [postsQuery whereKey:@"geoPoint" nearGeoPoint:[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:[city[@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[city[@"longitude"] doubleValue]] withinKilometers:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"distanceCovered"] doubleValue]];
}
[postsQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[postsQuery includeKey:@"user_id"];
[postsQuery whereKeyExists:@"user_id"];
[postsQuery setLimit:10];
```